# How does Affreza inhalable insulin affect lungs in patients without lung disease?

Tags: type-1-diabetes, inhalation

[Affreza's website](https://www.afrezza.com/) mentions side effects in patients with chronic lung disease.

Given that insulin injections can cause [lipohypertrophy](http://www.healthline.com/health/diabetes/lipohypertrophy), what is the risk of inhaling insulin in this regard?